# How to update 'Place of Suppy' and 'Location' for India GST in invoices through python quickbook api

Tags: python-2.7, quickbooks-online

As per GOI norms, it is necessary to provide a "Place of supply" in the invoice. However, I was unable to find a provision to update the place of supply & "Location" using the python Quickbooks API. Please guide how can I add place of supply & location via python quickbook API.

Comment: Were you able to get this working ?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [API docs](https://developer.intuit.com/app/developer/qbo/docs/api/accounting/all-entities/invoice) **ShipFromAddr** looks like the field you are looking for. If not, then you can setup up to 3 custom fields on the invoice.

Comment: I have used ShipAddr, BillAddr & TransactionLocationType = 07, .... (07 according to api docs ) but Please of supply not updated.